# Marker in Polygon path

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I managed to center a marker inside a polygon path by extending the `getBounds` method:

```
//polyline
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.getBounds = function() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    this.getPath().forEach(function(e) {
        bounds.extend(e);
    });
    return bounds;
};
```

All I have to do is this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: flight_path.getBounds().getCenter()
});
```

Now I want the marker to be at 10%, 25% or 95% of the path.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Geometry library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical) to work this out.  Add `libraries=geometry` to the Google Maps JS URL.

Then use the interpolate function to work out what percentage along your polyline you place your marker.

```
var inBetween = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(startLatlng, endLatLng, 0.5);  // 50%
```

This is simple on one polyline, but if you have multiple lines forming one path, it might be a bit trickier!  You could then maybe use computeLength to calculate the overall path length, do the maths yourself for where 95% is, and then I'm not sure...

Comment: Yes, in fact as it's using the .spherical. class, it's designed for geodesic lines

Comment: Hi. I load a KmlLayer containing a path taken from walking directions, which I would like to place markers along at specific points (mile markers for example). Would this work for my purposes

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not (although I've not used KML layers myself as yet)